# Jquery doesn't extend external json files

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

The function below looks like right but it works incorrectly

```
$.when(
    $.getJSON('compare/As_edit.json'), $.getJSON('compare/As_old.json'))
    .then(function (a,b) {
        //return $.extend(a, b);
        console.log($.extend(a, b));
    })
```

In console log I see:

```
Object {text: "As", icon: "icons/tree.png", children: Array[1]}
```

While it should be "children: Array[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146217/merge-2-arrays-of-objects)"

My files look like:

file1

```
{
  "text": "As",
  "icon": "icons/tree.png",
  "children": [
    {
      "text": "Class1",
      "children": [
        {
          "text": "Intern1",
          "-ORDER": "2",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "--TRT",
              "text": "Name of Intern"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "text": "Intern2",
          "-ORDER": "2",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "--TRT",
              "text": "Name of Intern"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

file2

```
{
  "text": "As",
  "icon": "icons/tree.png",
  "children": [
    {
      "text": "Class2",
      "children": [
        {
          "text": "Intern3",
          "-ORDER": "2",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "--TRT",
              "text": "Name of Intern"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "text": "Intern4",
          "-ORDER": "2",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "--TRT",
              "text": "Name of Intern"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

and in output I want to see

```
{
  "text": "As",
  "icon": "icons/tree.png",
  "children": [
    {
      "text": "Class1",
      "children": [
        {
          "text": "Intern1",
          "-ORDER": "2",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "--TRT",
              "text": "Name of Intern"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "text": "Intern2",
          "-ORDER": "2",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "--TRT",
              "text": "Name of Intern"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "text": "Class2",
      "children": [
        {
          "text": "Intern3",
          "-ORDER": "2",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "--TRT",
              "text": "Name of Intern"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "text": "Intern4",
          "-ORDER": "2",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "--TRT",
              "text": "Name of Intern"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

But I am only getting output from the object in file2
What's wrong?

this is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/owto07sz/) example

after checked reference on [Merge 2 arrays of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146217/merge-2-arrays-of-objects), I have used next code

```
 $.when(
        $.getJSON('compare/Astella_edit.json'), $.getJSON('compare/Astella_old.json'))
        .then(function (a,b) {
            var arr3 = [];
            for (var i in a) {
                var shared = false;
                for (var j in b)
                    if (b[j].children == a[i].children) {
                        console.log('['+ (b[j].children == a[i].children) +']');
                        shared = true;
                        break;
                    }
                if (!shared) arr3.push(a[i])
            }
            arr3 = arr3.concat(b);
            console.log(arr3);
            //return arr3;
        })
```

and it is merged to me almost correct

```
[Object, Object, "success", Object]
```

so the first object is file1, second is file2

what is "success" mean in generated JSON and Where is the third object coming from?

Comment: try console.log()-ing a and b seperately see what is given back by the callback function

Comment: you need to do deep extend ... read docs ... try `$.extend(true,a, b)`

Comment: @glcheetham, console shows for a - [Object, "success", Object]" and inside file1, for b - "[Object, "success", Object]" inside file2

Comment: @charlietfl, deep extend do same

Comment: create a demo with sample data

Comment: @charlietfl https://jsfiddle.net/owto07sz/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're expecting that `$.extend` will auto**magically** **merge** your `children` Array:

```
/*file1*/ {"children" : ["a"]}
```

`$.extend`*ed* with:

```
/*file2*/ {"children": ["b"]}
```

will **never** become:

```
/*result*/ {"children": ["a", "b"]}
```

**That's not the way $.extend works**:
the result will always be: `/*result*/ {"children": ["b"]}` !

Take this for example:

```
var ob1 = {
  a : ["a"],
  b : ["b"]
};
var ob2 = {
  a : ["a"],
  b : ["XXX"],
  c : ["c"]
};
$.extend(ob1, ob2);
console.log( ob1 ); // {a: ["a"], b:["XXX"], c:["c"]}
```

as you can see `$.extend` actually "extended" and updated the object `ob1` with the values from the `ob2` object, but the property `b` did**n't** become `["b", "XXX"]`

**How to merge two arrays of objects**? [Merge 2 arrays of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146217/merge-2-arrays-of-objects)

Comment: thank you a lot for explanation. Is there any way to merge it?

Comment: @Anton head to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146217/merge-2-arrays-of-objects

Comment: thanks, I already has read those link and unfortunately underscore.js doesn't work with external files. Will try to learn more deep...

Comment: please check updated question

Comment: @Anton refer to: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/ . TLDR; when's `.than()` uses three callbacks, you're not interested in `a` and `b` (three response statuses each) but actually at the first `data` response: `a[0]` and `b[0]`

Comment: for (var i in a[0]) {
                var shared = false;
                for (var j in b[0])
                    if (b[j].children == a[i].children) {
                        shared = true;
                        break;
                    }
                if (!shared) arr3.push(a[i])
            }
            arr3 = arr3.concat(b);
            console.log(arr3); console log says children undefined

Comment: @Anton use `.then(function (oa, ob) { var a=oa[0], b = ob[0];` but anyways with that code you recently added I think you'll get the same result as using jQuery's `$.extend`...

Comment: exactly same, what's wrong now?

Comment: @Anton what you're trying to accomplish is not that easy. You need to **recursively loop all properties of an object**. When looping your primary logic should be: if a==b than o[i]=a. if a==Array && b==Array than o[i]=[a+b] etc etc etc

Comment: got it.. thank you so much for your help