# How to combine two array objects if a key value matches in both arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, merge, javascript-objects

I am trying to combine two array objects with different array objects based on flight key.
If the value is matched in `a2`, I want to merge it with `a1` and create new array.
All data in `a1` must be there and matched flight details must be added from `a2` to `a1`.

Please help me to solve this.

```
a1 = [{'flight':'AF1223','oring':'CDF', 'Dest':'HNG'},{'flight':'XG23','oring':'HYD', 'Dest':'MMZ'},{'flight':'PK145','oring':'XYZ', 'Dest':'PEK'}]

a2 = [{'price':230,'avail':20,'flight':'AF1223'}, {'price':430,'avail':30,'flight':'DF43'},{'price':430,'avail':30,'flight':'XG23'} ]

combine array = [{'flight':'AF1223','oring':'CDF', 'Dest':'HNG','price':230,'avail':20},{'flight':'XG23','oring':'HYD', 'Dest':'MMZ'},{'flight':'PK145','oring':'XYZ', 'Dest':'PEK','price':430,'avail':30,}]
```

Comment: Have you tryed something, or just ordering a code ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146217/merge-2-arrays-of-objects

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette i am new to coding and trying to get hands on, with my knowledge i tried few but dnt work so requested for help

Comment: @ChadMcGrath i checked that one before i raised this question, i need a way to check if value matches and only join to a1 if matches else keep it as is.

Answer (score 2):

I am giving you a complete solution.

```
a = [
  {'id':'A','oring':'CDF', 'Dest':'HNG'},
  {'id':'B','oring':'HYD', 'Dest':'MMZ'},
  {'id':'C','oring':'XYZ', 'Dest':'PEK'}];

b = [
  {'id':'A','price':230,'avail':20,}, 
  {'id':'D','price':430,'avail':30},
  {'id':'B','price':430,'avail':30} ];

// put the object D into array a
for(var i=0;i<b.length;i++) {
  var idb = b[i].id;
  var idnotfound = true;
  a.forEach(function(rowofa) {
    var ida = rowofa.id;
    if(ida == idb) {
      idnotfound = false;
    }
  });
  if(idnotfound){
    a.push(b[i]);
  }
}//for
//console.log('aa=>>',a);
//.......................................

//Match ids and then put all in array a

for(var i= 0;i<a.length;i++) {
  var ida = a[i].id;
  for(var j=0;j<b.length;j++) {
    var idb = b[j].id;
    if(ida == idb) {
      a[i].avail = b[j].avail;
      a[i].price = b[j].price;
    }//if
  } //for2
}//for1
console.log('aa=>',a);
```

The output will be

```
aa=> [ { id: 'A', oring: 'CDF', Dest: 'HNG', avail: 20, price: 230 },
       { id: 'B', oring: 'HYD', Dest: 'MMZ', avail: 30, price: 430 },
       { id: 'C', oring: 'XYZ', Dest: 'PEK' },
       { id: 'D', price: 430, avail: 30 } ]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code-only answers are discouraged because they do not explain how they resolve the issue in the question. Consider updating your answer to explain what this does and how it addresses the problem - this will help not just the OP but others with similar issues. Please review [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over two arrays and if match push object from array2 ito array1, something like..

```js
var a1 = [{'flight':'AF1223','oring':'CDF', 'Dest':'HNG'},{'flight':'XG23','oring':'HYD', 'Dest':'MMZ'},{'flight':'PK145','oring':'XYZ', 'Dest':'PEK'}];

var a2 = [{'price':230,'avail':20,'flight':'AF1223'}, {'price':430,'avail':30,'flight':'DF43'},{'price':430,'avail':30,'flight':'XG23'} ];

var result = a1.slice(0);

for (var i = 0 ; i < result.length ; i++){
  for (var j = 0; j < a2.length ; j++){
    if (result[i].flight == a2[j].flight){
      result[i].price = a2[j].price;
      result[i].avail = a2[j].avail;
    }
  };  
};
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Perhaps `Object.assign(a, b)` would be closer to the desired solution? (Or any other way of merging two objects.) Of course that'd mutate `a1`, so another array, combined, could be created, followed by (on match) `combined.push(Object.assign({}, a, b));`

Comment: @Lucas Costa , thank you for helping hand, but the results is not one i was trying to get, if you see the combined array of example first object will have 5 key value pairs which is made of combination of a1 and a2 since flight number matched and second object will be just 3 key value pairs because no flight number was matching.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion @DawsonToth, I'm aggre with you and Redu asnwered based in `Object.assign`.

Comment: Note that this still mutates `a1` because `result = a1` is an assignment by reference to the original array. `result = a1.slice(0)` would leave `a1` unchanged.

Comment: Thanks @DawsonToth

Answer (score 0):

To match your desired output you can do as follows;

```js
var a1 = [{'flight':'AF1223','oring':'CDF', 'Dest':'HNG'},{'flight':'XG23','oring':'HYD', 'Dest':'MMZ'},{'flight':'PK145','oring':'XYZ', 'Dest':'PEK'}],
    a2 = [{'price':230,'avail':20,'flight':'AF1223'}, {'price':430,'avail':30,'flight':'DF43'},{'price':430,'avail':30,'flight':'XG23'}],
result = a2.reduce((p,c) => (p[c.flight] && (p[c.flight] = Object.assign(p[c.flight],c)),p), a1.reduce((f,s) => (f[s.flight] = s,f),{}));
console.log(result);
```