# Merge multiple arrays of objects with different IDs

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I need to merge multiple json objects by common IDs. My issue is that my objects have different keys for the ID.

```
var object1 = [
  { "name":"apples" ,"w": 1, "x": 2 },
  { "name":"banana" ,"w": 1, "x": 2 },
  { "name":"cherry" ,"w": 1, "x": 2 },
];
var object2 = [
  { "type":"banana" ,"y": 3, "x": 4 },
  { "type":"cherry" ,"y": 3, "x": 4 },
];
```

I would like to obtain :

```
var object1 = [
  { "name":"apples" ,"w": 1, "x": 2 },
  { "name":"banana" ,"w": 1, "x": 4, "y": 3 },
  { "name":"cherry" ,"w": 1, "x": 4, "y": 3 },
];
```

I want to use the same Array [object1] instead of creating a new one.
I created a [codepen here](https://codepen.io/BastienAustin/pen/ObKeXa)

Comment: what if a second `object2` would contain uncommon fruit like `{ "type":"lime" ,"y": 2, "x": 4 }` ? What should be  the result in such case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge 2 arrays of objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146217/merge-2-arrays-of-objects)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reduce()` to create new array and find to check if object with same name exists in `object2` object with same type.

```js
var object1 = [
  { "name":"apples" ,"w": 1, "x": 2 },
  { "name":"banana" ,"w": 1, "x": 2 },
  { "name":"cherry" ,"w": 1, "x": 2 },
];
var object2 = [
  { "type":"banana" ,"y": 3, "x": 4 },
  { "type":"cherry" ,"y": 3, "x": 4 },
];


var result = object1.reduce(function(r, e) {
  var o = object2.find(a => e.name == a.type);
  r.push(o ? Object.assign({}, e, {x: o.x, y: o.y}) : e);
  return r;
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Hey, your solution worked awesome, the issue I have now it that ie doesn't  take .find Do you know how to get over that ?

Answer (score 2):

Loop through `object2` and update the *fruits* if found using [`Array.prototype.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) - see demo below:

```js
var object1 = [{ "name":"apples" ,"w": 1, "x": 2 },{ "name":"banana" ,"w": 1, "x": 2 },{ "name":"cherry" ,"w": 1, "x": 2 }];
var object2 = [{ "type":"banana" ,"y": 3, "x": 4 },{"type":"cherry" ,"y": 3, "x": 4 }];

object2.forEach(function(e){
  var found = object1.find(function(k){
    return k.name === e.type;
  });
  if(found) {
    found.x = e.x;
    found.y = e.y;
  }
});

console.log(object1);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a solution for your problem, can you try it ?

```js
var object1 = [
  { "name":"apples" ,"w": 1, "x": 2 },
  { "name":"banana" ,"w": 1, "x": 2 },
  { "name":"cherry" ,"w": 1, "x": 2 },
];
var object2 = [
  { "type":"banana" ,"y": 3, "x": 4 },
  { "type":"cherry" ,"y": 3, "x": 4 },
];

function mergeObject(obj1,obj2){
    var obj3 = {};
    for (var attrname in obj1) { obj3[attrname] = obj1[attrname]; }
    for (var attrname in obj2) { obj3[attrname] = obj2[attrname]; }
    return obj3;
}

function mergeObjectInArray(firstArray,  firstArrayKey, secondaryArray, secondaryArrayKey) {
  var resultArray = new Array();
  for(var firstArrayIndex in firstArray) {
    var firstArrayObject = firstArray[firstArrayIndex];
    var resultArrayObject = firstArrayObject;
    for(var secondaryArrayIndex in secondaryArray) {
    var secondaryArrayObject = secondaryArray[secondaryArrayIndex];
      if(firstArrayObject[firstArrayKey] === secondaryArrayObject[secondaryArrayKey]) {
        resultArrayObject = mergeObject(firstArrayObject,secondaryArrayObject);
        delete resultArrayObject[secondaryArrayKey];
      }
    }
    resultArray.push(resultArrayObject);
  }
  return resultArray;
  
}

var resultArray = mergeObjectInArray(object1, "name", object2, "type");


// Assuming JSON.stringify - not available in IE<8
console.log(JSON.stringify( resultArray ) );
```