# Merge two array of objects with same keys, some object won't have the same value?

Tags: javascript, python, arrays, object

I want to merge two arrays of objects. The keys are the same but the values might not always be the same.

Any solution is appreciated preferably in javascript, but a python solution is fine as well.

Here is the sample data:

```
var g= [ 
    { id: 36, name: 'AAA', goal: 'yes' , 'random':27},
    { id: 40, name: 'BBB', goal: 'yes' },
    { id: 39, name: 'JJJ', goal: 'yes' },
    { id: 27, name: 'CCC', goal: 'yes' , lag: "23.3343"}];


var c= [ 
    { id: 36, name: 'AAA', goal: 'yes', color:"purple" },
    { id: 40, name: 'BBB', circle: 'yes', color:"purple" },
    { id: 100, name: 'JJJ', circle: 'yes'} ];
```

My expected output should be :

```
 var finalData = [{
 { id: 36, name: 'AAA', goal: 'yes' ,'random':27, color:"purple"},
 { id: 40, name: 'BBB', circle: 'yes', color:"purple"},
 { id: 39, name: 'JJJ', goal: 'yes' },
 { id: 27, name: 'CCC', goal: 'yes' ,lag: "23.3343"},
 { id: 100, name: 'JJJ', circle: 'yes' }

  }]
```

Here is my current code, it works to some degree but it doesn't add keys it might have missed.

```
var finalData = [];
for(var i in g){
   var shared = false;
   for (var j in c)
       if (c[j].name == g[i].name) {
           shared = true;
           break;
       }
   if(!shared) finalData.push(g[i])
}
finalData = finalData.concat(c); 

finalData
```

Comment: What is there both has the same key say `goal`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge 2 arrays of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146217/merge-2-arrays-of-objects)

Answer (score 4):

You could use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) for keeping same `id` in the same object and [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) for creating independent objects.

```js
var g = [{ id: 36, name: 'AAA', goal: 'yes', 'random': 27 }, { id: 40, name: 'BBB', goal: 'yes' }, { id: 39, name: 'JJJ', goal: 'yes' }, { id: 27, name: 'CCC', goal: 'yes', lag: "23.3343" }],
    c = [{ id: 36, name: 'AAA', goal: 'yes', color: "purple" }, { id: 40, name: 'BBB', circle: 'yes', color: "purple" }, { id: 100, name: 'JJJ', circle: 'yes' }],
    map = new Map,
    result = g.concat(c).reduce(function (r, o) {
        var temp;
        if (map.has(o.id)) {
            Object.assign(map.get(o.id), o);
        } else {
            temp = Object.assign({}, o);
            map.set(temp.id, temp);
            r.push(temp);
        }
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Version without reduce and without concat.

```js
function merge(o) {
    var temp;
    if (map.has(o.id)) {
        Object.assign(map.get(o.id), o);
        return;
    }
    temp = Object.assign({}, o);
    map.set(temp.id, temp);
    result.push(temp);
}

var g = [{ id: 36, name: 'AAA', goal: 'yes', 'random': 27 }, { id: 40, name: 'BBB', goal: 'yes' }, { id: 39, name: 'JJJ', goal: 'yes' }, { id: 27, name: 'CCC', goal: 'yes', lag: "23.3343" }],
    c = [{ id: 36, name: 'AAA', goal: 'yes', color: "purple" }, { id: 40, name: 'BBB', circle: 'yes', color: "purple" }, { id: 100, name: 'JJJ', circle: 'yes' }],
    map = new Map,
    result = [];

[g, c].forEach(function (a) {
    a.forEach(merge);
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

With dynamic key.

```js
function mergeBy(key, data) {
    return Array.from(data
        .reduce((m, o) => m.set(o[key], { ...m.get(o[key]), ...o }), new Map)
        .values()
    );
}

var g = [{ id: 36, name: 'AAA', goal: 'yes', 'random': 27 }, { id: 40, name: 'BBB', goal: 'yes' }, { id: 39, name: 'JJJ', goal: 'yes' }, { id: 27, name: 'CCC', goal: 'yes', lag: "23.3343" }],
    c = [{ id: 36, name: 'AAA', goal: 'yes', color: "purple" }, { id: 40, name: 'BBB', circle: 'yes', color: "purple" }, { id: 100, name: 'JJJ', circle: 'yes' }],
    result = mergeBy('id', [...g, ...c]);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Can you explain what   r.push(temp) does because r is not an array. Also when I tried this solution with a bigger data set it only returns only the last object instead of all of the objects it looped through. I am thinking its because reduce only returns a single value. I switched reduce with a map and it didn't work either .

Comment: `r` is the accumulartor from reduce callback. it has as initial value an empty array.

Comment: when I tried this solution with a bigger data set it only returns only the last object instead of all of the objects it looped through. I am thinking its because reduce only returns a single value. I switched reduce with a map and it didn't work either

Comment: it is always returning all objects which are consolidated. version 2 works without reduce now.

Comment: @NinaScholz Will the above solution (with reduce) works for large data sets?

Comment: @Vishnu, you could try it. i thing the second one performs better.

Comment: @NinaScholz sure i will try. Could you please help me to check this query? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63628199/update-the-array-with-attributes-from-different-array-with-same-key-for-both-j

Comment: If I want to give the 'id' column dynamically and pass along with this function what changes do we need to make?

Comment: @Toros91, you could take a closure over the key and store the retuned function and use it like `merge` but with `o[key]` instead of `o.id`.

Comment: `[g, c].forEach(function (a) { a.forEach(merge);` in this how do we call?

Comment: please see third approach.

Comment: sorry for the trouble, one last question if we want to left join instead of inner join?

Comment: @Toros91, you could try yourself and ask a new question, because an answer would not fit above and not in commets.

Comment: @NinaScholz: posted the question here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66985164/two-arrays-left-join-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Python solution. This modifies `g`, which you may or may not want.

```
c_by_id = {d['id']: d for d in c}
for item in g:
    item.update(c_by_id.get(item['id']), {})
```

Comment: I think OP wants a JavaScript solution, since his attempt shows so.

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily achieved by underscore functions `_.uniq` and `_.union`.

Just use this:

```
var finalData = _.uniq(_.union(c, g),  function (ele)  {
                    return ele.id
                })
```

This will return you what you are looking for.