# Merge related objects from two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to merge related objects from two arrays.

```
var arr1 = [{thing: 'house', material: 'wood', location: 'earth'}, {thing: 'brick-wall', material: 'brick', location: 'moon'}];
var arr2 = [{property: 'made from wood', location: 'earth'}, {property: 'made from brick', location: 'moon'}];
```

Is it possible to join the two arrays in a way that will add the property value from arr2 to arr1 where `arr1.location === arr2.location`?

Comment: join means mutation or do you want new objects? please add what you have tried?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Please search before you ask. This kind of question has been asked many, many times before.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge two array of objects with same keys, some object won't have the same value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47713659/merge-two-array-of-objectsjson-with-same-keys-some-object-wont-have-the-same)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use spread syntax with `.map()` and `.find()` array methods.

```js
let arr1 = [
    {thing: 'house', material: 'wood', location: 'earth'},
    {thing: 'brick-wall', material: 'brick', location: 'moon'}
];
let arr2 = [
    {property: 'made from wood', location: 'earth'},
    {property: 'made from brick', location: 'moon'}
];

let result = arr1.map(o1 => ({
    ...o1, 
    property: arr2.find(o2 => o2.location === o1.location).property
}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Alternatively you can use `Object.assign()`:

```js
let arr1 = [
    {thing: 'house', material: 'wood', location: 'earth'},
    {thing: 'brick-wall', material: 'brick', location: 'moon'}
];
let arr2 = [
    {property: 'made from wood', location: 'earth'},
    {property: 'made from brick', location: 'moon'}
];

let result = arr1.map(o1 => Object.assign(
  {property: arr2.find(o2 => o2.location === o1.location).property}, o1
));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

**Description:**

- `.map()` will create a new array from the results of callback function.
- `.find()` will give us the object in second array where value of `location` property matches the property in current object being traversed in callback.

**Useful Resources:**

- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)
- [`Spread syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Answer (score 0):

You could concatenate the arrays. I assume you'd want to re-order from there or modify your key:value pairs, but pushing the two arrays into one is pretty straight forward at least.

```
var newArray = arr1.concat(arr2);
```

This will produce a new array called "newArray" but will leave your existing arrays as they stand.

Comment: He wants to merge objects of both arrays, not concatenating them.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
arr1.map(i1 => 
  ({ ...i1, property: (arr2.find(i2 => i2.location === i1.location) || {}).property }));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and build new objects as result

```js
var arr1 = [{ thing: 'house', material: 'wood', location: 'earth' }, { thing: 'brick-wall', material: 'brick', location: 'moon' }],
    arr2 = [{ property: 'made from wood', location: 'earth' }, { property: 'made from brick', location: 'moon' }],
    map = new Map,
    result;

[arr1, arr2].forEach(a =>
    a.forEach(o => map.set(o.location, Object.assign(map.get(o.location) || {}, o))));

result = Array.from(map, ([k, v]) => v);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: You should mark this question as a clear duplicate instead of producing [similar answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47714013/906113) over and over again.