# Replace data of an array with the data from another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an array

```
    const data = [
    {
      id: 0,
      identifier: 'free-2020',
      name: '<I18nText id="pricing.plans.name.free" />',
      planTitle: 'free',
      price: '00',
      freeSearches: '<I18nText id="pricing.plans.features.unlimited" />',
      freeBookings: '<I18nText id="pricing.plans.features.unlimited" />',
      travelerProfiles: '<I18nText id="pricing.plans.features.unlimited" />',
      supportTickets: '<I18nText id="pricing.plans.features.available" />',
      supportByPhone: ' - ',
      supplierChannels: ' - ',
      customDomain: ' - ',
      active: true,
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      identifier: 'basic-2020',
      name: '<I18nText id="pricing.plans.name.basic" />',
      planTitle: 'basic',
      price: '29',
      freeSearches: '<I18nText id="pricing.plans.features.unlimited" />',
      freeBookings: '<I18nText id="pricing.plans.features.unlimited" />',
      travelerProfiles: '<I18nText id="pricing.plans.features.unlimited" />',
      supportTickets: '<I18nText id="pricing.plans.features.available" />',
      supportByPhone: ' - ',
      supplierChannels: ' 1 ',
      customDomain: ' - ',
      active: false,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      identifier: 'standard-2020',
      name: '<I18nText id="pricing.plans.name.standard" />',
      planTitle: 'standard',
      price: '59',
      freeSearches: '<I18nText id="pricing.plans.features.unlimited" />',
      freeBookings: '<I18nText id="pricing.plans.features.unlimited" />',
      travelerProfiles: '<I18nText id="pricing.plans.features.unlimited" />',
      supportTickets: '<I18nText id="pricing.plans.features.available" />',
      supportByPhone: ' 1hr/mo ',
      supplierChannels: ' 2 ',
      customDomain: ' - ',
      active: false,
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      identifier: 'professional-2020',
      name: '<I18nText id="pricing.plans.name.professional" />',
      planTitle: 'professional',
      price: '99',
      freeSearches: '<I18nText id="pricing.plans.features.unlimited" />',
      freeBookings: '<I18nText id="pricing.plans.features.unlimited" />',
      travelerProfiles: '<I18nText id="pricing.plans.features.unlimited" />',
      supportTickets: '<I18nText id="pricing.plans.features.available" />',
      supportByPhone: ' 3hr/mo ',
      supplierChannels: ' 5 ',
      customDomain: 'Yes',
      active: false,
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      identifier: 'custom-2020',
      name: '<I18nText id="pricing.plans.name.custom" />',
      planTitle: 'custom',
      price: ' - ',
      freeSearches: '<I18nText id="pricing.plans.features.unlimited" />',
      freeBookings: '<I18nText id="pricing.plans.features.unlimited" />',
      travelerProfiles: '<I18nText id="pricing.plans.features.unlimited" />',
      supportTickets: '<I18nText id="pricing.plans.features.available" />',
      supportByPhone: '<I18nText id="pricing.plans.features.unlimited" />',
      supplierChannels: '<I18nText id="pricing.plans.features.unlimited" />',
      customDomain: '<I18nText id="pricing.plans.features.available" />',
      active: false,
    },
  ];
```

and another array

```
const plans = [
{id: 2, identifier: "professional-2020", name: "professional", currencyCode: "usd", price: "99.0"},
{id: 3, identifier: "free-2020", name: "free", currencyCode: "usd", price: "0.0"},
{id: 4, identifier: "basic-2020", name: "basic", currencyCode: "usd", price: "29.0"},
{id: 5, identifier: "standard-2020", name: "standard", currencyCode: "usd", price: "59.0"},
{id: 6, identifier: "custom-2020", name: "custom", currencyCode: "usd", price: "999.0"},
]
```

Now I want to put the data from the `plans` array to `data` array by matching the `identifier` key. So the `id`, `identifier`, `name`, `price` data of the `data` array will be replaced by the values of these keys of the `plans` array. Seems like I need to map these data from the two arrays to another array? or maybe not. How can I implement this functions. Need code examples.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update the array with attributes from different array with same key for both - javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63628199/update-the-array-with-attributes-from-different-array-with-same-key-for-both-j)

Comment: What output you want

Comment: @SourabhSomani I want to replace some data of the `data` array with some data from the `plans` array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = data.map(d => {
  const correspondingPlan = plans.find(plan => d.identifier === plan.identifier);
  if (correspondingPlan) {
    return {...d, ...correspondingPlan};
  } else {
    return d
  }
})
```

Edit: `Array.prototype.find` is not supported in IE. Here's a solution with filter:

```
data = data.map(d => {
  const correspondingPlan = plans.filter(plan => d.identifier === plan.identifier)[0];
  if (correspondingPlan) {
    return {...d, ...correspondingPlan};
  } else {
    return d
  }
})
```

Comment: array.find() is not supported in IE, could you please mention another way supported in IE, like array.filter()

Comment: working version 

``const planData = data.map(d => {
    const correspondingPlan = plans.filter(
      plan => d.identifier === plan.identifier,
    )[0];
    if (correspondingPlan) {
      return { ...d, ...correspondingPlan };
    } else {
      return d;
    }
  });``

Comment: @ashfaqrafi I've updated my answer with your solution using `filter`

Answer (score 0):

```js
const plansById = {};
plans.forEach((plan) => {
  plansById[plan.identifier] = plan;
});


data.forEach((line) => {
  line.plan = plansById[line.planTitle];
  // You should probably add some null-check in case of a missing or wrong planTitle
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can `reduce` to generate the expected results.

```
data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    const found = plans.find(p => p.identifier === curr.identifier)
    if(found) {
        return [...acc, {...curr, ...found}];
    } else {
        return [...acc, { ...curr }]
    }
    return acc;
}, [])
```