# How I can merge two arrays objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I need merge two arrays of `objects`, and no duplicates, with `es6` syntax. In my task few more keys in objects.

But I think this is not problem. In `array2` always objects that are contained inside `array1`

Here is the array

```
array1 = [
   {name: 'one', count: 0}, 
   {name: 'two', count: 0}, 
   {name: 'three', count: 0},
   {name: 'four', count: 0} 
]

array2 = [
   {name: 'two', count: 4},
   {name: 'four', count: 2}
]
```

I need get this:

```
array3 = [
  {name: 'one', count: 0},
  {name: 'two', count: 4},
  {name: 'three', count: 0},
  {name: 'four', count: 2}
]
```

Comment: We can guide you or unblock you, but you have to make an attempt first. Please show what you've tried so far.

Comment: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146217/merge-2-arrays-of-objects) Try solutions on this link.

Comment: if in array1 you have an tem with count 1 for example, and in the array 2 you have the same item with count 2, what will be the count value of the item included in the final array?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge 2 arrays of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146217/merge-2-arrays-of-objects)

Answer (score 1):

```js
const array1 = [
  {name: 'one', count: 0}, 
  {name: 'two', count: 0}, 
  {name: 'three', count: 0},
  {name: 'four', count: 0} 
]
const array2 = [
  {name: 'two', count: 4},
  {name: 'four', count: 2}
]

const result = array1.map(a => {
  const b = array2.find(b => b.name === a.name);
  if (b) {
    return {name: a.name, count: a.count + b.count}
  }
  return a;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let all = array1.concat(array2)
//avoid dupplicates by  key
let map = all.reduce((acc,item)=>{acc[item.name] = item; return acc;},{});
//convert map back to array
let array3 = Object.values(map)
console.log(array3);
//
[ { name: 'one', count: 0 },
  { name: 'two', count: 4 },
  { name: 'three', count: 0 },
  { name: 'four', count: 2 } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

`map` can be used to call a function on each element of an array. The main difference with the version using `find` is that it will go through all elements of `array2`, so that if you have 2 elements with `name: 'two'` in the array, both of them will increment the count. With `find` only the fist found will add.

```js
const array1 = [
  {name: 'one', count: 0}, 
  {name: 'two', count: 0}, 
  {name: 'three', count: 0},
  {name: 'four', count: 0} 
  ],
  array2 = [
  {name: 'two', count: 4},
  {name: 'four', count: 2}
  ];

const array3 = array1.map(obj => {
  let _count = obj.count;
  array2.forEach(obj2 => {
    if(obj2.name === obj.name){
      _count += obj2.count;
    }
  });
  return { name: obj.name, count: _count };
});
    
console.log(array3);
```

EDIT: modified following @HMR suggestion (thanks pointing my mistake) + used `forEach` on array2 because i don't use any returned array

Comment: map should not be used to mutate the array it's used on. Better to use forEach instead or return a new object.