# Merge two array of objects and added a new Key & Value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 arrays based on the "Form_Name" key value to merge an array with added new key&value "isChecked".

Array One

```
arrayOne = [
{id: 11, Form_Name: "form name One", isChecked: true}
{id: 11, Form_Name: "form name Two", isChecked: true}];
```

Array Two

```
arrayTwo = [
{Form_Name: "form name One", Form_AddDate: "2019-05-15T11:03:18.05"}
{Form_Name: "form name Two", Form_AddDate: "2019-05-15T11:03:18.05"}
{Form_Name: "form name Three", Form_AddDate: "2019-05-15T11:03:18.05"}
{Form_Name: "form name Four", Form_AddDate: "2019-05-15T11:03:18.05"}];
```

Expected merged array

```
mergedArray = [
{Form_Name: "form name One", Form_AddDate: "2019-05-15T11:03:18.05", isChecked: true}
{Form_Name: "form name Two", Form_AddDate: "2019-05-15T11:03:18.05", isChecked: true}
{Form_Name: "form name Three", Form_AddDate: "2019-05-15T11:03:18.05", isChecked: false}
{Form_Name: "form name Four", Form_AddDate: "2019-05-15T11:03:18.05", isChecked: false}]
```

I tried like below

```
const mergedArray = [];
for (let i = 0; i < arrayTwo.length; i++) {
  mergedArray.push({
   ...arrayTwo[i],
   ...(arrayOne.find((itmInner) => itmInner.Form_Name === arrayTwo[i].Form_Name))}
  );
}
console.log('merged array result', mergedArray);
```

Comment: _what have you tried?_

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge 2 arrays of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146217/merge-2-arrays-of-objects)

Comment: Ayush Gupta. Updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 const hasChecked = new Set(arrayOne.map(it => it.Form_Name));

 const result = arrayTwo.map(it => ({ ...it, isChecked: hasChecked.has(it.Form_Name) }));
```

By creating a set of checked form names, you can easily map over the second array of objects, and add a `isChecked` property.

Comment: While this approach works, it is not efficient to create a `Set` and iterating over the array anyways

Comment: This solution has linear time complexity, while all other solutions provided have quadratic complexity. So this is the most efficient solution so far (in terms of performance)

Comment: Instead of a Set though, mapping the array to an object would work better

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arrayOne = [{
  id: 11,
  Form_Name: "form name One",
  isChecked: true
}, {
  id: 11,
  Form_Name: "form name Two",
  isChecked: true
}];

let arrayTwo = [{
  Form_Name: "form name One",
  Form_AddDate: "2019-05-15T11:03:18.05"
}, {
  Form_Name: "form name Two",
  Form_AddDate: "2019-05-15T11:03:18.05"
}, {
  Form_Name: "form name Three",
  Form_AddDate: "2019-05-15T11:03:18.05"
}, {
  Form_Name: "form name Four",
  Form_AddDate: "2019-05-15T11:03:18.05"
}];

let arrayOneObj = arrayOne.reduce((result, item) => {
  result[item.Form_Name] = item.isChecked
  return result;
}, {})

const result = arrayTwo.map((item) => ({ ...item,
  isChecked: !!arrayOneObj[item.Form_Name]
}))

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if the form_name is in the same order in both arrays.

```
arrayOne = [
{id: 11, Form_Name: "form name One", isChecked: true},
{id: 11, Form_Name: "form name Two", isChecked: true},
{id: 11, Form_Name: "form name Three", isChecked: true},
{id: 11, Form_Name: "form name Four", isChecked: true}]

arrayTwo = [
{Form_Name: "form name One", Form_AddDate: "2019-05-15T11:03:18.05"},
{Form_Name: "form name Two", Form_AddDate: "2019-05-15T11:03:18.05"},
{Form_Name: "form name Three", Form_AddDate: "2019-05-15T11:03:18.05"},
{Form_Name: "form name Four", Form_AddDate: "2019-05-15T11:03:18.05"}]

let mergedArray = []

arrayTwo.forEach( (item,i) => { mergedArray.push(Object.assign({}, item, arrayOne[i]))} )

console.log(mergedArray)
```

Hope it helps !