# Adding array into an array item

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am populating a json file and I have an array like this

```
[{ name: name, address: address, age: age }]

[{ name2: name2, address2: address2, age2: age2 }]
```

Now, I want to merge these two arrays and I'm expecting a result like this

```
[
    { name: name, address: address, age: age },
    { name2: name2, address2: address2, age2: age2 }
]
```

Comment: So what's the question? What's the problem? What have you tried so far?

Comment: `const array3 = [...array1, ...array2];`?

Comment: Please see the link below https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146217/merge-2-arrays-of-objects?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: Please see the link below
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146217/merge-2-arrays-of-objects

Answer (score 2):

Another option...

```
var array1 = [{ name: name, address: address, age: age }]
var array2 = [{ name2: name2, address2: address2, age2: age2 }]

var merged = array1.concat(array2)
```

Comment: I am getting a result like this [{array1},{array2},{array3},{array4}] and i am expecting result like this [{array1{array3}},{array2{array4}}]

Comment: Your expected result contradicts your original question. You should post the code that you have tried in your question so people can provide a more satisfying answer.

Answer (score 1):

```js
    const a = [{ name: 'name1', address: 'address1', age: 22 }];
    
    const b = [{ name2: 'name2', address2: 'address2', age2: 23 }];
    
    const result = [...a, ...b];
    
    console.log(result);
```

Comment: I am getting a result like this [{array1},{array2},{array3},{array4}] and i am expecting result like this [{array1{array3}},{array2{array4}}]