# How to merge objects from two arrays

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays of objects

```
    let current = [
        {
            categoryId: 18,
            id: 'fire_18',
            test: 'test'
        }, {
            oldItem: "items that dont exist in new array should be deleted"
        }
    ]

    let new_data = [
        {
            id: 'fire_18',
            categoryId: 18,
            test1: 'test1',
        }, {
            newItem: "new items should be added to final"
        }
    ]
```

I need to merge those so the result is not missing data from `current` array. The desired result looks like this

```
    [
        {
            id: 'fire_18',
            categoryId: 18,
            test1: 'test1',
            test: 'test'
        }, {
            newItem: "new items should be added to final"
        }
    ]
```

Here is my attempt

```js
let current = [
    {
        categoryId: 18,
        id: 'fire_18',
        test: 'test'
    }, {
        oldItem: "items that dont exist in new array should be deleted"
    }
]

let new_data = [
    {
        id: 'fire_18',
        categoryId: 18,
        test1: 'test1',
    }, {
        newItem: "new items should be added to final"
    }
]

console.log(' === Current ==>', current);
console.log(' === New ==>', new_data);

new_data.map(newItem => {
    let currentMatch;
    try { // incase new item newItem.categoryId wont exist
        currentMatch = current.find(c => c.categoryId == newItem.categoryId) || {};
    } catch (error) { // in that case, no need to merge
        currentMatch = {};
    }
    return Object.assign(currentMatch, newItem);
});
console.log(' === Merged ==>', new_data);
```

the main thing wrong still is `test` key from the `current` arr is missing after merge.

Can anyone modify the pen to not delete keys from the `current` arr?

Comment: I've gone ahead and edited your question to include your attempt as a snippet in the question itself, as opposed to an external link. In the future, please make sure all necessary code is *in the question itself*. Users shouldn't have to visit a second website to see the complete question :)

Comment: Where did `name` and `slugName` come from in your expected results?

Comment: @Maria it was old irrelevant data from a prev version. I edited my question to reflect more accurately.

Comment: Are `newItem` and `oldItem` actually in the data?

Comment: Please refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19480008/javascript-merging-objects-by-id

Answer (score 1):

Note that `Array.map` method returns a new array. You are not logging this merged new array - but one of your old arrays.

Also, you don't need `try catch` here. You may also note that if the `categoryId` is undefined, the objects will still match. So, you need a check for that.

```js
let current = [
    {
        categoryId: 18,
        id: 'fire_18',
        test: 'test'
    }, {
        oldItem: "items that dont exist in new array should be deleted"
    }
]

let new_data = [
    {
        id: 'fire_18',
        categoryId: 18,
        test1: 'test1',
    }, {
        newItem: "new items should be added to final"
    }
]



newArray = new_data.map(newItem => {
    let currentMatch;
        
        
     currentMatch = current.find(c => c.categoryId === newItem.categoryId && newItem.categoryId) || {};
  
  
    return Object.assign(currentMatch, newItem);
});
console.log(' === Merged ==>', newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use lodash for this.

```
finalArr = _(_.flatten([current, new_data]))
                                        .groupBy('id')
                                        .map(_.spread(_.assign))
                                        .value();
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this? I'm not sure what you're expecting to happen with the `newItem` and `oldItem` entries.

```js
let current = [{
  categoryId: 18,
  id: 'fire_18',
  test: 'test'
}]

let new_data = [{
  id: 'fire_18',
  categoryId: 18,
  test1: 'test1',
}]

const result = Object.values([...current, ...new_data].reduce((acc, {
  categoryId,
  ...other
}) => ({
  ...acc,
  [categoryId]: {
    categoryId,
    ...other
  }
}), {}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use es6 spread operator to meet your requirement

```js
  var current = [{
    categoryId: 18,
    id: 'fire_18',
    name: 'Servers',
    slugName: 'fire_18',
    test: 'test'
}]

var new_data = [{
    id: 'fire_18',
    categoryId: 18,
    name: 'Servers',
    slugName: 'fire_18'
}]

const results = new_data.map(item => {
    let newItem = { ...item };
    const currentMatchItem = current.find(c => c.categoryId == newItem.categoryId);

    if (currentMatchItem) {
        newItem = { ...currentMatchItem, ...newItem };
    }

    return newItem;
});

console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41919138/6525081).
On your code it goes like that:

```js
let current = [
    {
        categoryId: 18,
        id: 'fire_18',
        test: 'test'
    }, {
        oldItem: "items that dont exist in new array should be deleted"
    }
]

let new_data = [
    {
        id: 'fire_18',
        categoryId: 18,
        test1: 'test1',
    }, {
        newItem: "new items should be added to final"
    }
]

function merge(a, b, prop){
  var reduced = a.filter(function(aitem){
      return ! b.find(function(bitem){
          return aitem[prop] === bitem[prop];
      });
  });
  return reduced.concat(b);
}
console.log(merge(current, new_data, "id") );
```

Comment: this is great. but `test` is missing from `current[0]` in the merged results

Comment: Well @Charlie's solutions much more modern anyways (: