# merge array object with pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need to merge two arrays with objects inside with JavaScript.

How can this be done?

I am currently using this code, but it is not for me:

```
var array_merge = [];
var array_one = [
  {
    label: "label",
    value: "value",
  },
  {
    label: "label",
     value: "value",
  },
];
array_merge.push(array_one);
var array_two = [
  {
    label: "label",
    value: "value",
  },
  {
    label: "label",
     value: "value",
  },
];
array_merge.push(array_two);
```

How can I join them so that the result is the following?

```
var array_merge = [
  {
    label: "label",
    value: "value",
  },
  {
    label: "label",
    value: "value",
  },
  {
    label: "label",
    value: "value",
  },
  {
    label: "label",
    value: "value",
  },
];
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you have a new question, feel free to click "new question" to ask it.  The last edit to this question completely changed its purpose.

Comment: @prieber I can’t write new question..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [concat method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) to merge arrays

> The concat() method is used to merge two or more arrays. This method does not change the existing arrays, but instead returns a new array.

```js
const array_one = [
  {
    label: "label",
    value: "value",
  },
  {
    label: "label",
     value: "value",
  },
];
const array_two = [
  {
    label: "label",
    value: "value",
  },
  {
    label: "label",
     value: "value",
  },
];

const array_merge = array_one.concat(array_two);

console.log(array_merge)
```

Comment: At the end I've solved with the code in this ticket:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146217/merge-2-arrays-of-objects
Thanks anyway!