# Javascript: How Do you Combine Two Objects Into One

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to combine two object arrays using either Javascript or Jquery but it is not resulting the way I am expecting it to be. These are my array objects results:

Arry1 Results: `[{"name": "2412"}, {"name": "3324"}, {"name": "8875"}]`

Arry2 Results: `[{"zip": "12051"}, {"zip": "54021"}, {"zip": "24521"}]`

This is what I have done to push one into the other:

```
Array.prototype.push.apply(Arry1,Arry2);
```

The issue is the above code stacks them together. The object structure I am trying to get is as follows:

```
[ 
{
 "name": "2412",
 "zip": "12051"
},
{
 "name": "3324",
 "zip": "54021"
},
{
"name": "8875",
 "zip": "24521"
}
]
```

Comment: It seems like you want to "zip" the objects in the two arrays. `Arry1.map((obj, index) => ({ ...obj, ...Arry2[index] }))`?

Comment: What happens if one of the arrays has a property with the same name?

Comment: `result = Arry1.map((v, i) => Object.assign({}, v, Arry2[i]));`

Comment: See also [Merge 2 arrays of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7146217/215552)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map the arrays into each other by cloning and combining with `Object.assign`

```js
let a1 = [{"name": "2412"}, {"name": "3324"}, {"name": "8875"}];

let a2 = [{"zip": "12051"}, {"zip": "54021"}, {"zip": "24521"}];

let result = a1.map((props, index) => Object.assign(props, a2[index]));

console.log(result);
```

---

**Edit Based on Comment:**

If this is a utility you're going to be using often with a variable number of arrays, you may consider creating a function that handles it.

```js
    let a1 = [{"name": "2412"}, {"name": "3324"}, {"name": "8875"}],
    a2 = [{"zip": "12051"}, {"zip": "54021"}, {"zip": "24521"}],
    a3 = [{"phone": "1234"},{"phone": "3121"},{"phone": "2136"}];


function combine(first, ...arrs) {
  let result = first.map((props, index) => {
    let combined = [props];
    arrs.forEach(arr => combined.push(arr[index]));
    return Object.assign(...combined);
  })
  return result;
};


let result = combine(a1, a2, a3);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Would this work with 3 object arrays as well?

Comment: @Zeusox I updated my answer to cover that.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do this. The below is one of,

```js
let array1 = [{"name": "2412"}, {"name": "3324"}, {"name": "8875"}];
let array2 = [{"zip": "12051"}, {"zip": "54021"}, {"zip": "24521"}];
let resultArray = [];
for(let i=0; i< array1.length; i++) { // we can consider any of array1 or array 2 length
  resultArray.push({...array1[i], ...array2[i]});
}
console.log(resultArray);
```

**OR**

With Jquery, we can go like below,

```
let array1 = [{ name: "2412" }, { name: "3324" }, { name: "8875" }];
let array2 = [{ zip: "12051" }, { zip: "54021" }, { zip: "24521" }];

let resultArray = [];
$.each(array1, function(index, value) {
   resultArray.push($.extend(value, array2[index]));
});
console.log(resultArray);
```

Comment: Would this work with 3 object arrays as well?

Comment: Yes, we have to change push statement like, resultArray.push({...array1[i], ...array2[i], ...array3[i]});

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map`:

```js
const arr1 = [{"name": "2412"}, {"name": "3324"}, {"name": "8875"}];

const arr2 =  [{"zip": "12051"}, {"zip": "54021"}, {"zip": "24521"}];

let result = arr1.map((obj, idx) => {
      obj.zip = arr2[idx].zip; 
      return obj
  });

console.log(result)
```