# Merge each element from two arrays of object javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, merge

Let the two arrays be:

```
const names = [{name: "Bla"}, {name: "BlaBla"}];
const ages= [{age: 15}, {age: 20}];
```

I Want the new array to be

```
newArray = [{name: "Bla", age: 15}, {name: "BlaBla", age: 20}]
```

Comment: Hi Mahmoud, welcome to StackOverflow! You will need to add additional details to your question, like what you have tried already, where you are stuck, and so on.

Comment: You can use `.map()` to loop over one of the arrays, and `Object.assign()` to merge it with the corresponding element of the other array.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge 2 arrays of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146217/merge-2-arrays-of-objects)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const names = [{name: "Bla"}, {name: "BlaBla"}];
const ages= [{age: 15}, {age: 20}];
const newArray = [];

let i = 0;

while (names[i] && ages[i]) {
  newArray.push({ ...names[i], ...ages[i] });
  i += 1;
}

console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 3):

This is known as the zip operation - for which you can use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) - combined with object merge, either through [spread operator](http://MDN%20documentation) or [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

The callback passed to `map()` will receive the element and index of an array as its first two arguments respectively; you then use the index to retrieve the value from the other array.

```js
const names = [{name: "Bla"}, {name: "BlaBla"}];
const ages= [{age: 15}, {age: 20}];

result = names.map((name, index) => Object.assign({}, name, ages[index]))

console.log(result)
```

*Note that `Object.assign()` is used with three arguments, the first one being an empty object; without that, the first argument would get updated in-place as a side effect*

Comment: One thing to be aware of when using `Object.assign()` is that the first parameter is the target object, which is the one that gets modified (mutated).

If you didn't want to modify the objects in the names array, you should use `Object.assign({}, name, ages[index])` instead.