# Update array of objects with array of objects

Tags: javascript

My apologies if this has been addressed before, but I couldn't get it to work with anything I found.

Assume I have 2 arrays - `arr1`, `arr2`. I want to update the objects in `arr1` if the the property `id` matches in `arr1` and `arr2`. Objects that exist in `arr2` but not in `arr1` - meaning the property `id` does not exist in `arr1` - should be pushed to `arr1`.

Example:

```
let arr1 = [
  {id: 0, name: "John"},
  {id: 1, name: "Sara"},
  {id: 2, name: "Domnic"},
  {id: 3, name: "Bravo"}
]

let arr2 = [
  {id: 0, name: "Mark"},
  {id: 4, name: "Sara"}
] 

# Expected Outcome

let outcome = [
  {id: 0, name: "Mark"},
  {id: 1, name: "Sara"},
  {id: 2, name: "Domnic"},
  {id: 3, name: "Bravo"},
  {id: 4, name: "Sara"}
]
```

Comment: Please include what you found and what you've tried so that people don't waste their time giving you answers you've already tried. For instance, this looks exactly the same as [Merge 2 arrays of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7146217/215552)...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge 2 arrays of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146217/merge-2-arrays-of-objects)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) for this:

```js
const arr1 = [
  {id: 0, name: "John"},
  {id: 1, name: "Sara"},
  {id: 2, name: "Domnic"},
  {id: 3, name: "Bravo"}
];

const arr2 = [
  {id: 0, name: "Mark"},
  {id: 4, name: "Sara"}
];

arr2.reduce((res, item) => {
  const existingItem = res.find(x => x.id === item.id);
  if (existingItem) { existingItem.name = item.name; }
  else { res.push(item); }
  return res;
}, arr1);

console.log(arr1);
```

Comment: Aha, difference of just a few seconds again :D

Comment: Haha yes, again :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```js
 let arr1 = [
      {id: 0, name: "John"},
      {id: 1, name: "Sara"},
      {id: 2, name: "Domnic"},
      {id: 3, name: "Bravo"}
    ]

    let arr2 = [
      {id: 0, name: "Mark"},
      {id: 4, name: "Sara"}
    ] 
    
    var res = arr1.reduce((acc, elem)=>{
       var x = arr2.find(i=>i.id === elem.id);
       
       if(x){
          acc.push(x)
       }else{
         acc.push(elem)
       }
       return acc
    }, []);
    
    console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to mutate the objects in `arr1` rather than creating new ones, one way to do it would be using [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) to iterate the objects in `arr2` and then check if there's already an object with the same `id` in `arr1` using [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

- If there is one, you mutate it with [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).
- Otherwise, push the new object to `arr1`:

```js
const arr1 = [
  { id: 0, name: 'John' },
  { id: 1, name: 'Sara' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Domnic' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Bravo' },
];

const arr2 = [
  { id: 0, name: 'Mark', sometingElse: 123 },
  { id: 2, foo: 'bar' },
  { id: 4, name: 'Sara' },
];

for (const currentElement of arr2) {
  let previousElement = arr1.find(el => el.id === currentElement.id);
  
  if (previousElement) {
    Object.assign(previousElement, currentElement);
  } else {
    arr1.push(currentElement);
  }
}

console.log(arr1);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to try something different you can use foreach and filter to achieve this

```
let arr1 = [
  {id: 0, name: "John"},
  {id: 1, name: "Sara"},
  {id: 2, name: "Domnic"},
  {id: 3, name: "Bravo"}
]

let arr2 = [
  {id: 0, name: "Mark"},
  {id: 4, name: "Sara"}]


  arr1.forEach(x=>{
    arr2.forEach(y=>{
      if(x.id==y.id){
        x.name=y.name
      }
    })
  })
 arr2.filter((a)=>{if(!arr1.some(b=>a.id==b.id)) arr1.push(a)})


  console.log(arr1)
```

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to use `Array.prototype.find` to sort this out!

```js
let arr1 = [
  {id: 0, name: "John"},
  {id: 1, name: "Sara"},
  {id: 2, name: "Domnic"},
  {id: 3, name: "Bravo"}
];

let arr2 = [
  {id: 0, name: "Mark"},
  {id: 4, name: "Sara"}
];

let updateArrayOfObjects = (arr1, arr2) => {
  for (let obj of arr2) {
    let item = arr1.find(v => v.id === obj.id);
    if (item) item.name = obj.name;
    else      arr1.push({ ...obj });
  }
  return arr1;
};

console.log(updateArrayOfObjects(arr1, arr2));
```