# How to push key/value pairs from for loop to existing array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to figure out how to properly push my key/value pairs that are returned from my for loop into an existing array of objects. As is stands right now, every time the for loop is ran, it pushes the new key/pair values to the array and removes the previous values.

setLabels is called on a click event and pulls values from this.state.exportEntries.

I'd like to push the values, from the for loop, to fillerArray without removing any data on setLabels rerun. Could someone point me in the right direction for achieving this?

Based on other users comments, a merge is what I'm looking for. However, as stated, I am working within a for loop and do not have two or more clearly defined arrays like array1 / array2 to merge.

The data gets pushed to fillerArray on every for loop and that is what's resetting it. However, I'm wondering if it's possible to preserver the previous values in fillerArray while adding to it on the next for loop.

If any further information is needed, please let me know.

**Code Structure**

```
setLabels = (e, itemId, itemLabel) => {

  let fillerArray = [];

  for (let item of this.state.exportEntries) {
    if (itemId in item) {
      fillerArray.push({ [itemLabel]: item[itemId] });
    }
  }

console.log(fillerArray);

}
```

**Current Output**

```
(7) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
  0: {First: "Name1"}
  1: {First: "Name2"}
  2: {First: "Name3"}
  3: {First: "Name4"}
  4: {First: "Name5"}
  5: {First: "Name6"}
  6: {First: "Name7"}
  length: 7
  __proto__: Array(0)

(7) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
  0: {Last: "Last1"}
  1: {Last: "Last2"}
  2: {Last: "Last3"}
  3: {Last: "Last4"}
  4: {Last: "Last5"}
  5: {Last: "Last6"}
  6: {Last: "Last7"}
  length: 7
  __proto__: Array(0)
```

**Desired Output**

```
(7) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
  0: {First: "Name1", Last: "Last1"}
  1: {First: "Name2", Last: "Last2"}
  2: {First: "Name3", Last: "Last3"}
  3: {First: "Name4", Last: "Last4"}
  4: {First: "Name5", Last: "Last5"}
  5: {First: "Name6", Last: "Last6"}
  6: {First: "Name7", Last: "Last7"}
  length: 7
  __proto__: Array(0)
```

Comment: You're looking for "merging" two arrays of objects.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge 2 arrays of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146217/merge-2-arrays-of-objects)

Comment: @HereticMonkey That seems to be what I'm after, but could you provide an example on how to do this within the for loop? From what I can see in that article, you'd have two arrays specifically named and I can't quite understand how that works in the for loop.

Comment: @HereticMonkey please observe the new edits to the question. Let me know if you have questions please.

Comment: Your output shows two arrays under Current Output. Capture those outputs in separate arrays and run the code in the answers to that question on those arrays. They do not need special names. Look at several answers and find the one that works best for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to merge two equally long arrays of object which can be done in the following manner:

```js
let merged = [];
for(var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    merged.push({...array1[i], ...array2[i]})
}
```

Comment: a) This is an answer to the duplicate question and b) you're missing the parentheses around the `push` call.