# Merge two arrays of objects with the same keys in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I would like to merge these two arrays

```
const arr1 = [{ label: 'one', value: 'one', type: 'arr1'}];
const arr2 = [{ label: 'two', value: 'two', type: 'arr1'}];
```

to get the following result

```
const arr3 = [{ label: 'one', value: 'one' type: 'arr1'}, { label: 'two', value: 'two' type: 'arr1'}];
```

I've tried `arr1.concat(arr2)` and `_.merge(arr1, arr2)` and `[arr1, arr2]` and get the following error

```
TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance.
In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method.
```

Comment: You're missing a comma before `type` making it an invalid syntax

Comment: If you fix the syntax error, you won't get the error message (at least not with `.conat()` and `[arr1, arr2]`). So... -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> [mcve]

Comment: In my code I have the comma, just a mistake when I was writing some dummy code for this question. Thanks for point it out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge 2 arrays of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146217/merge-2-arrays-of-objects)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your third try `[arr1, arr2]` was really close to a right answer, you can use the new spread syntax `(...)` to concat the arrays by doing to following:

```js
const arr1 = [{ label: "one", value: "one", type: "arr1" }];
const arr2 = [{ label: "two", value: "two", type: "arr1" }];

console.log([...arr1, ...arr2]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code it works fine :

```js
 const arr1 = [{ label: 'one', value: 'one', type: 'arr1'}];
        const arr2 = [{ label: 'two', value: 'two', type: 'arr1'}];
        const arr3 = arr1.concat(arr2);
        
        console.log(arr3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed comma before `type`

But you can solve it that way.

```js
const arr1 = [{ label: 'one', value: 'one', type: 'arr1'}];
const arr2 = [{ label: 'two', value: 'two', type: 'arr1'}];

const arr3 = arr1.concat(arr2);

console.log(arr3);
```