# JavaScript merge arrays unshift with unique IDs

Tags: javascript, typescript, javascript-objects

I've two arrays of objects:

```
var arr1 = [{
  "id": "id_1",
  "name": "Skoda"
}, {
  "id": "id_2",
  "name": "BMW"
}];

var arr2 = [{
  "id": "id_1",
  "name": "Skoda - Auto"
}, {
  "id": "id_3",
  "name": "BMW - Auto"
},{
  "id": "id_4",
  "name": "Merc - Auto"
}]
```

Output

```
var arr1 = [{
  "id": "id_3",
  "name": "BMW - Auto"
},{
  "id": "id_4",
  "name": "Merc - Auto"
},{
  "id": "id_1",
  "name": "Skoda"
}, {
  "id": "id_2",
  "name": "BMW"
}];
```

I want to merge two arrays arr1 & arr2, basically I want to unshift the object from arr2 to the arr1 only if the Id is not present in arr1, Hence we're not adding `id_1` to the arr1. I'm not sure how can we achieve it

I tried the below way but it keeps on adding duplicate items, how can I avoid duplication of id

```
arr1.unshift.apply(arr1, arr2)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146217/merge-2-arrays-of-objects The accepted answers results in duplication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reduce all the datasets onto a `Map`.

For each item in a dataset, prioritize the first occurrence by assigning it last.

**Note:** `accInner` is technically `accOuter`, but they are distinguished as separate variables for the sake of the accumulator argument for each `reduce` operation. They are both references to the `Map()` initializer.

Also, `k` is the value of the `id` field (key) of `item[key]`. I used an IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Execution) to avoid creating a block-scope and assigning it as a variable.

```js
// First occurrence of `name` and `a` stays
const arr1 = [
  { "id": "id_1", "name": "Skoda", "a": 1 },
  { "id": "id_2", "name": "BMW" }
];

// Do not override `name` or `a`, but add `b`
const arr2 = [
  { "id": "id_1", "name": "Skoda - Auto", "a": 0, "b": 2 },
  { "id": "id_3", "name": "BMW - Auto" },
  { "id": "id_4", "name": "Merc - Auto" }
];

const mergeByKey = (key, ...dataSets) =>
  [...dataSets
    .reduce((accOuter, dataSet) =>
      dataSet.reduce((accInner, item) =>
        ((k) =>
          accInner.set(k, Object.assign({}, item, accInner.get(k)))) // priority
        (item[key]), accOuter), new Map)
    .values()]

const arr3 = mergeByKey('id', arr1, arr2); // Priority is left-to-right

console.log(arr3);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```